# Remove polygon line after shapefile reprojection

Tags: coordinate-system, r

I have a shapefile of the Bering Sea in the Pacific Ocean I've been working with in R. It was originally split down the middle, so I reprojected it to Mollweide to connect them (image example attached). The only problem is that there's still the boundary line down the middle. How would I get rid of it? They aren't two polygons that can be combined with Dissolve for some reason. Any advice would be greatly appreciatined. Here is my code so far:

```
library(rgdal)
Bering_Sea<- readOGR("Bering_Sea.shp")

Bering_Transform<- spTransform(Bering_Sea, CRS("+proj=moll +lon_0=150 +ellps=WGS84"))

plot(Bering)
plot(Bering_Transform)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would try making a new feature class, then copying and pasting the two into it, while you're in the projection you like, then merging them via editor...

Comment: Why can't they be dissolved?

Comment: What does dim or length tell you? If there are, in fact, two polygons, create a new column, in the @data slot, that contains identical values (eg. new.id = c(1,1) ) and then use rgeos::gUnaryUnion(Bering_Transform, id = Bering_Transform@data$new.id)